# Definitions and theorem numbering

Tags: theorems, amsthm

I am new to theorems and definitions of the `amsthm` package and what I am trying to achieve might be really simple.

I have the following theorems:

```
\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{matriceDef}{Matrice}[section]
\newtheorem{matriceSomma}[matriceDef]{Somma}
\newtheorem{matriceSommaProp}{Proprietà per la somma tra matrici}[matriceSomma]
```

defined in a file. When I actually put them all together I have a `LaTeX Error: No counter 'matriceSomma' defined.` That happens at the last line.

What I am trying to do is have the last definition be a sub-definition of the preceding one. Right now, as you can see, 
[image: output]
the output is correct, what I want. The problem is that it gives that error there.

The MWE for this is this one

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathtools,calrsfs,mathrsfs,amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{matriceDef}{Matrice}[section]
\newtheorem{matriceSomma}[matriceDef]{Somma}
\newtheorem{matriceSommaProp}{Proprietà per la somma tra matrici}[matriceSomma]
\begin{document}

    \section{Matrici}

    \subsection{Definizioni e teoremi}

    \begin{matriceDef}
      Foo, bar
    \end{matriceDef}

    \begin{matriceSomma}      
      Outside
    \end{matriceSomma}

    \begin{matriceSommaProp}
      Inside
    \end{matriceSommaProp}

\end{document}
```

I removed the useless typesetting. What I would like to do is create a definition (or a theorem) that depends on another for numbering. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You forgot to copy the matriceDef theorem environment that you refer in the first newtheorem in the mwe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're stating that `matriceSomma` uses the same counter as `matriceDef`, so no `matriceSomma` counter is defined.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{matriceDef}{Matrice}[section]
\newtheorem{matriceSomma}[matriceDef]{Somma}
\newtheorem{matriceSommaProp}{Proprietà per la somma tra matrici}[matriceDef]

\begin{document}

\section{Matrici}

\subsection{Definizioni e teoremi}

\begin{matriceDef}
  Foo, bar
\end{matriceDef}

\begin{matriceSomma}  
  Outside
\end{matriceSomma}

\begin{matriceSommaProp}
  Inside
\end{matriceSommaProp}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, you'll have to define scores of such theorem-like environments, because there's the product of matrices and the product of matrices by scalars and whatnot; I propose defining just two and passing the real name at use time.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{innerDef}{\envargument}[section]
\newtheorem{innerSubDef}{\envargument}[innerDef]

\newcommand{\envargument}{}
\newenvironment{Def}[1]
 {\renewcommand{\envargument}{#1}\innerDef}
 {\endinnerDef}
\newenvironment{SubDef}[1]
 {\renewcommand{\envargument}{#1}\innerSubDef}
 {\endinnerSubDef}


\begin{document}

\section{Matrici}

\subsection{Definizioni e teoremi}

\begin{Def}{Matrice}
  Foo, bar
\end{Def}

\begin{Def}{Somma}  
  Outside
\end{Def}

\begin{SubDef}{Proprietà per la somma tra matrici}
  Inside
\end{SubDef}

\end{document}
```

By the way, shouldn't it be “Proprietà della somma fra matrici”?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I was just missing that part. I really like the other solution too, I might consider using it, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @gjkf Have a look at the suggestions I added.

Comment: Just saw them and really like that solution too, thanks a bunch! And yes, it should be, was just transcribing what I wrote down during lectures.

Comment: I have a little problem of the same kind so I thought not to create another question. When I add more sub theorems like `\newtheorem{matriceDifferenzaProp}{Proprietà per la differenza tra matrici}[matriceDef]` the last number stays the same (e.g. both have the number 1.2.1 and not 1.2.1 and 1.2.2).

Comment: @gjkf Oh, that's why I suggested to do it differently!

Comment: @gjkf By the way, what are the outstanding properties of matrix subtraction? I know none, which is the reason why subtraction is not defined as an operation between matrices, where A–B simply means A+(–B).

Comment: Absolutely none :P I just needed some more things to add to test stuff :) I will then use your other solution, thanks!